# bad shim signature you need to load the kernel first

Tags: boot, kernel

I recently installed linux-image-6.2.0-26-generic this kernel. and when ever i try to boot my system it doesn't load and give me an error message of bad shim signature you need to load the kernel first
then i have to manually chose the older version of kernel.how can i go back to my old kernel or what is the solution of this problem

Comment: Current kernel version, as of today, for the 6.2 chain is 6.2.0-37. Most users should not need to manually install specific kernel versions, so there seems some element of your problem that you have not mentioned.

Comment: yes you are right.my wifi was not working so i saw some youtube video in them they told me that if i update my kernel than it will fix the issue. that's why i manually updated my kernel.

Comment: @RakibulIslam please install the latest `linux-generic` meta-package to helps install the latest version of `linux-image-$VER-generic` . There is a hwe series of kernels which usually have all the latest drivers, but the meta-package name contains the ubuntu version number too, for example `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` for 20.04 etc. Details at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack